# How to add + and - to my menu tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I would like to add a plus and minus icons to my expandable tabs. I was thinking using css or javascript to replace an icon when the tab is click but I have no idea how to go about it

This is what I have so far 
HTML

```
<h1>Responsive Tabs</h1>

<div class="tabBox">
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Test1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Test2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Test3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tabContainer"> <a onclick="toggle('tab1');" href="#tab1">Test1</a> 
    <div id="tab1" class="tabContent" style="display:none;">Test1</div>
<a onclick="toggle('tab2');" href="#tab2">Test2</a>

    <div id="tab2" class="tabContent" style="display:none;">Test2</div>
<a onclick="toggle('tab3');" href="#tab3">Test3</a>

    <div id="tab3" class="tabContent" style="display:none;">Test3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
      $(".tabContent").hide();
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
$(".tabContent:first").show();

$("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".tabContent").hide();
  var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  $(activeTab).fadeIn();
  return false;
    });

  function toggle(target) {

  var artz = document.getElementsByClassName('tabContent');
  var targ = document.getElementById(target);
  var isVis = targ.style.display == 'block';

  // hide all
  for (var i = 0; i < artz.length; i++) {
      artz[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  // toggle current
  targ.style.display = isVis ? 'none' : 'block';

  return false;
  }
```

The rest in on my jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jnewguy/5B5KJ/63/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a stab at your code and added a simple jquery code to show you how to toggle between '+'  and '-' icon. Note that for this example, i used text, but you can replace the text by an image and so on.

Here is the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5B5KJ/68/)

In your TabContainer link I changed it this way. Instead of using inline javascript function call onClick, you can simplify everything by giving a main class to all your headers. Next you can add a custom attribute, in this case 'data-content' to which you give the id of the tab you wish to display. Inside the link tag, i added a 'span' tag with the '+' text.

```
<a class="myTabHeader" data-content="tab1" href="#tab1">Test1 <span class="toggle-icon">+</span></a>
```

In order to toggle your tab, I added this bit of jquery. We create an Onclick event for our main tab header class. Once a click is made, we can extract the id of the tab to display by getting the value of our custom attribute. Next we can select all content tabs with jquery to hide everything. Once this is done, you can use the id to display the current content tab. Again, with jquery, we target all toggle icon and reset everything. Finally, you can use the 'this' selector, that refers to the current 'myTabHeader' that was clicked and you can search its children elements with jquery '.find(x)' method. This way, you can then call the '.text("string")' to change, well, the text.

```
//On Document ready
$(function(){
    //Click event for our Accordion Tab Headers
    $('.myTabHeader').click(function(){
        //Get which tab to display
        var openTab = $(this).attr('data-content');
        //Close all visible tabs
        $('.tabContent').css({
            display:'none'
        });
        //Display our selected tab
        $('#'+openTab).css({
            display:'block'
        });
        //Reset icon
        $('.toggle-icon').text("+");
        //Change icon for currently opened tab
        $(this).find('.toggle-icon').text("-");
    });
});
```

Of course, like I said, you could add an image in the span element instead of text. Then you could just change this part:

```
//Reset icon
$('.toggle-icon img').attr('src','/images/path-to-Plus-icon-image.jpg');
//Change icon for currently opened tab
$(this).find('img').attr('src','/images/path-to-Minus-icon-image.jpg');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you! it works well, but when I open a tab, how can I reclose it? because in order to close an open tab I need to click on another tab

Comment: Here you go, I updated the jquery click event. What I did is set up a kind of boolean flag by adding a specific 'opened' class to the tab that was clicked. Then in the click event, i check to see if this particular element has this class appended. If true, we close the currently opened content panel, else we do like before and open a new panel and close everyone else. [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5B5KJ/69/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to get expandable content correct? You can use jQuery UI tabs for expanding and closing the content. You can get a preview of this function here:

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#collapsible

The code would be the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Collapse content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-  ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      collapsible: true
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

You could then use CSS or an IMG tag to style your tabs.